# Feynman Diagrams for pion production in proton-proton collisions

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, pions

I have a conceptual question about the Feynman Diagrams representing pion production at the LHC. When trying to draw the FD for this process, I have drawn two possibilities, and I'm not sure which is lowest order; I have been discussing with a fellow student and we both think differently. Apologies in advance for the lack of labels on the diagrams, the program I used to draw them apparently didn't export the labels on the quarks. Both cases involve just two protons, two gluons, and a neutral pion.

In the first case we have drawn one the protons exchanging a gluon, and then afterwards the excited proton emitting a second gluon which allows for pair production of the neutral pion;

[image]

In the second case we have both protons emitting gluons, leading to pair production and gluon absorption.

[image]

The course is very phenomenological in its approach and not mathematical at all (we haven't covered QFT at all, and most of the arguments are based on hand waving), so we can't say for sure, but we think that the two processes are both valid and probably the Feynman diagrams are equivalent, but we just aren't sure. Thanks, and sorry for the fairly basic question.

Comment: You need to add a few more gluons because colored particles, gluons, cannot produce color singlet hadrons. For example, a single gluon cannot produce a pion, and two nucleons cannot interact by single gluon exchange

Comment: Believe it or not, that's not even in the course...

Comment: In general one counts the vertices to see if the diagrams are of equal rank. Yes, strong interactions make a mess with colors etc. You will have to study more than handwaving phenomenology